# Correct way to uninstall SQL Server 2008 ( or above )

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, installation

Since University I've been facing this problem...

How do I uninstall SQL Server?

What I've done is delete everything in "control panel" related to SQL Server.

But, is there a *right* way to uninstall everything?

Comment: This MSDN link covers everything you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143412.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty much all there is to it. You may want to backup or transfer your database files/backups before the un-installation process, but getting rid of the application is that simple.

[As per Mirosoft Support KB 955499,](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955499)

> 1. Open the Programs and Features item in Control Panel.To do this, click Start, type appwiz.cplin the Start Search box, and then click
>      appwiz.cpl in the Programs list.
> 2. Select the SQL Server component to
>      uninstall, and then click Change/Remove. This will start the SQL
>      Server Installation Wizard.
> 3. Setup Support
>      Rules will run to verify your computer configuration. To continue,
>      click Ok.
> 4. On the Select Instance page, use the drop-down box to
>      specify an instance of SQL Server to remove, or specify the option
>      to remove only the SQL Server shared features and management tools.
>      To continue, click Next.
> 5. On the Select Features page, specify the
>      features to remove from the specified instance of SQL Server. To
>      continue, click Next.
> 6. Removal Rules will run to verify that the
>      operation can complete successfully.
> 7. On the Ready to Uninstall page,
>      review the list of components and features that will be uninstalled.
> 8. The Setup Progress page will display Setup status.
> 9. On the Completing Setup page, click Close to exit the Installation Wizard.
> 10. Repeat
>       steps 2-9 until all SQL Server 2008 components have been removed.

Comment: Thanks. That's what i do. i thought there was some other faster way to do this.

Comment: Note that if you have Evaluation Edition and it has expired, or you have done aggressive cleanup in C:\Windows\Installer\, the Control Panel avenue may not work. [I've blogged about this for 2008 R2](https://sqlblog.org/2010/10/25/fun-with-software-uninstalling-sql-server-2008-r2-evaluation-edition) but it is applicable to 2008 - 2014 AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You're not the only one who's faced this problem, I assure you.
In the programs list you get a lot of `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (R2)` components to choose from.

If you wish to remove them all, just uninstall the one component that reads `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (R2)`.
You don't have to remove the component one by one in a hierarchical order or something like that. The setup will let you check all the components for removal.

The rest of the remaining components can be safely uninstalled. If you have a newer version of SQL server that depends on components (like documentation/drivers) from the old instance, the setup for the remaining components you wish to delete will warn you about the reference.